# How to create multi volume file backup using symantec backup.exec

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am using symantec backup .exec for backup and restore in mysql server . Now I am  in need to take  larger database backup  in tape .But it exeeds the tape storage and I am trying to create a multi volume file ie, a single backup in multiple tapes. Please do help me to sort out this .

Comment: I didn't know BackupExec had an agent for MySQL.  If it doesn't, then my first question is whether you've ever actually successfully *restored* one of the backups you're making... because just backing up the files isn't enough.

Comment: Yep I am able to restore and backup to tape through symantec backup.exec .But right now I am in a situation to take backup in multiple tapes cse the data size exeeds the tape size.